# Trouble with live USB Speed/Installation?

Tags: boot, partitioning, 20.04, usb

So... I've been messing with Ubuntu in live usb's for the past week or so (pretty much new to Ubuntu), at one point I decided to use a 128Gb USB 3.1 (gen 1) that I had lying around, I decided to make a 116Gb persistent partition in Rufus and it all went ok, I started customizing stuff and everything, installing programs, etc.

I was updating to Focal Fossa and decided to reboot, I ended up disconnecting the drive.
Everything was fine, I reinstalled the ISO into the USB and everything seems so slow now, like... almost unusable, it was fine yesterday before I had to re-format the drive.

Just if it's worth something:
I used Rufus both times to make an MBR 90Gb persistent partition, formatting with NTFS on a 4096kb cluster, also doing a double scan for bad blocks, what went wrong? atm I'm just reinstalling it again to see what happens. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

///Edit///: It works great if you make the partition use GPT and use NTFS with a 4096 cluster for formatting, it also takes a quarter of what it did with MBR.

I encountered another problems but they're not related to transfer speed or drive speed.

Comment: You formatted a device intended for Ubuntu with NTFS?

Comment: @Matigo Yup, was I not supposed to do it?

Comment: NTFS is a Windows file system. If you want something to be fast for Ubuntu, then you would need to stick to Linux file systems, such as `ext4`, `btrfs`, and `zfs`. The one exception would be if you are using the USB device to host a VM that runs with Windows as a host. In that situation, an NTFS partition would be the only logical way forward.

Comment: @Matigo Oh wow... That's interesting, Rufus only lets me format with NTFS or Large FAT32 tho, is there another program which I can use to make a persistent storage ext4 USB?

Comment: Try FAT32 and make it with Rufus because when I tried other application like etcher io it messed up the installation and grub doesn't appeared. @ElFrutero

Comment: Gonna try that asap @PiyushMhatre It's now formatting the 110Gb partition, I'll keep you updated

Comment: And yeah after installing format the live usb from Ubuntu, because you can select wether to format the usb with GPT (to make it accessable to new devices) and MBR (to make it accessable to old devices) partitioning scheme and lots of partition formats without installing any other third-party software :) @ElFrutero

Comment: Ooookay... So, now the Rufus formatting and ISO installation takes about 20 minutes instead of 2 hours, that's neat. Apparently I forgot to use MBR the last time so that's why it was so fast. Now the only thing is that when I update drivers/software, etc and reboot, it no longer detects the usb or something, it says 0.365513 Initframus unpackagin failed, and I can't move anything from there, I'll format it again but I'm confused about what I just experienced, is it normal? @PiyushMhatre

Comment: Okay no problem if your usb is no getting detected so click on activities on the top left corner and search for app name (disks) , then open it and select your usb and format it from there after then mount it by selecting it by left click and then click the play button now you can use it.@ElFrutero